# SwiftUI List cells not displaying selection state correctly after scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, list, swiftui, selection

EDIT: It happens on iOS 14.2 - 14.5, but not 14.1 or 14.0. It's a SwiftUI regression. I don't know a workaround so far.

---

I'm having issues with the SwiftUI List selection, when the user scrolls. Selected cells that get scrolled offscreen and then become visible again are not displayed as selected.

[image: SwiftUI List Selection issue]

Am I missing something or is this a SwiftUI bug?

It seems like the internal SwiftUI List coordinator is using UITableView and doesn't correctly update the cell state for the selection state.

```swift
struct Item: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id: Int
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var selectedItems: Set<Int>
  @Published var items: Array<Item>
  
  init() {
    self.items = [Item(id: 1), Item(id: 2), Item(id: 3), Item(id: 4), Item(id: 5),
                  Item(id: 6), Item(id: 7), Item(id: 8), Item(id: 9), Item(id: 10),
                  Item(id: 11), Item(id: 12), Item(id: 13), Item(id: 14), Item(id: 15),]
    self.selectedItems = []
  }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var context: ViewModel
     
    var body: some View {
//        Alternative also doesn't work.
//        List(context.items, id: \.id, selection: $context.selectedItems) { item in
//            Text("\(item.id)").id(item.id)
//        }
//        .environment(\.editMode, .constant(.active))
        
        List(context.items, selection: $context.selectedItems) { item in
            Text("\(item.id)")
        }
        .environment(\.editMode, .constant(.active))
        
    }
}
```

The console output:

> ListSelection[6659:3960182] [Assert] Attempted to call -cellForRowAtIndexPath: on the table view while it was in the process of updating its visible cells, which is not allowed. Make a symbolic breakpoint at UITableViewAlertForCellForRowAtIndexPathAccessDuringUpdate to catch this in the debugger and see what caused this to occur. Perhaps you are trying to ask the table view for a cell from inside a table view callback about a specific row? Table view: <*TtC7SwiftUIP33_BFB370BA5F1BADDC9D83021565761A4925UpdateCoalescingTableView: 0x10381ec00; baseClass = UITableView; ...; dataSource: <*TtGC7SwiftUIP10$1b198497819ListCoreCoordinatorGVS_20SystemListDataSourceSi_GOS_19SelectionManagerBoxSi**: 0x10340a930>>

Comment: What platform are you running on?  I just tried it on iOS 14.1 and it works (the only thigk I changed was increasing the number of items: `self.items = (0..<100).map(Item.init(id:))` ) so that it would actually scroll.

Comment: Sorry @JoshHomann only saw your comment now. It's 14.2.1 on an iPhone 12 Mini and 14.2 on an iPhone 8 / Simulator and Xcode 12.2 (12B45b). I didn't update yet to 12.3 as I heard it's unstable. True, more items are needed for bigger screens. I will try with 14.1, when the simulators are downloaded.

Comment: It indeed works fine for me on 14.1 simulators.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a Swift bug on 14.2-14.3 because my app had the selections working normally but now it's facing these exact same visual issues as described.